# 100 Join SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, normalization

I'm looking to essentially have a centralized table with a number of lookup tables that surround it. The central table is going to be used to store 'Users' and the lookup tables will be user attributes, like 'Religion'. The central table will store an Id, like ReligionId, and the lookup table would contain a list of religions.

Now, I've done a lot of digging into this and I've seen many people comment saying that a UserAttribute table might be the best way to go, essentially using an EAV pattern. I'm not looking to do this. I realize that my strategy will be join-heavy and that's why I ask this question here. I'm looking for a way to optimize those joins.

If the table has 100 lookup tables, how could it be optimized to be faster than just doing a massive 100 table inner join? Some ideas come to mind like using many smaller joins, sub-selects and views. I'm open to anything, including a combination of these strategies. Again, just to note, I'm not looking to do anything that's EAV-related. I need the lookup tables for other reasons and I like normalized data.

All suggestions considered!

Here's a visual look:

[image]

Edit: Is this insane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimization techniques will likely depend on the size of the center table and intended query patterns.  This is very similar to what you get in data warehousing star schemas, so approaches from that paradigm may help.

For one, ensuring the size of each row is absolutely as small as possible.  Disk space may be cheap, but disk throughput, memory, and CPU resources are potential bottle necks.  You want small rows so that it can read them quickly and cache as much as possible in memory.

A materialized/indexed view with the joins already performed allows the joins to essentially be precomputed.  This may not work well if you are dealing with a center table that is being written to alot or is very large.

Anything you can do to optimize a single join should be done for all 100.  Appropriate indexes based on the selectivity of the column, etc.

Depending on what kind of queries you are performing, then other techniques from data warehousing or OLAP may apply.  If you are doing lots of group by's then this is likely an area to look in to.  Data warehousing techniques can be applied within SQL Server with no additional tooling.

Ask yourself why so many attributes are being queried and how they are being presented?  For most analysis it is not necessary to join with lookup tables until the final step where you materialize a report, at which time you may only have grouped by on a subset of columns and thus only need some of the lookup tables.

Group By's generally should be able to group on the lookup Id's without needing the text/description from the lookup table so a join is not necessary.  If your lookups have other information relevant to the query at hand then consider denormalizing it into the central table to eliminate the join and/or make that discreet value its own lookup, essentially splitting the existing lookup ID into another ID.

You could implement a master code table that combines the code tables into a single table with a CodeType column.  This is not the same as EAV because you'd still have a column in the center table for each code type and a join for each, where as EAV is usually used to normalize out an arbitrary number of attributes.  (**Note**: I personally hate master code tables.)

Lastly, consider normalization the center table if you are not doing data warehousing.

Are there lots of null values in certain lookupId columns?  Is the table sparse?  This is an indication that you can pull some columns out into a 1 to 1/0 relationships to reduce the size of the center table.  For example, a Person table that includes address information can have a PersonAddress table pulled out of it.

Partitioning the table may improve performance if there's a large number of rows and you can determine that certain rows, perhaps with a certain old datetime from couple years in the past, would rarely be queried.

Update: See **"Ask yourself why so many attributes are being queried and how they are being presented?"** above.  Consider a user wants to know number of sales grouped by year, department, and product.  You should have id's for each of these so you can just group by those IDs on the center table and in an outer query join lookups for only what columns remain.  This ensures the aggregation doesn't need to pull in unnecessary information from lookups that aren't needed anyway.

If you aren't doing aggregations, then you probably aren't querying large numbers of records at a time, so join performance is less of a concern and should be taken care of with appropriate indexes.

If you're querying large numbers of records at a time pulling in all information, I'd look hard at the business case for this.  No one sits down at their desk and opens a report with a million rows and 100 columns in it and does anything meaningful with all of that data, that couldn't be accomplished in a better way.

The only case for such a query be a dump of all data intended for export to another system, in which case performance shouldn't be as much as a concern as it can be scheduled overnight.

Comment: I'm chewing your answer. Response to come.

Comment: I know this is a subjective question to ask you, but give my scenario, what would you do? And the center is going to be the largest table in the database, I noticed some of your observations were dependent upon its size.

Comment: Depends on the purpose of your queries.  I have updated answer with some examples of what I'm talking about.

Comment: There is no doubt I'll give you the check for this. I'm not doing aggregations. I'm just querying the data and I would like the potential to pull all of it at once, no matter the use-case. I would ideally like to avoid EAV and 100-joins, but it seems to me as if the EAV model might be best. If you were to distinctly choose between EAV and 100-joins, would you pick an EAV model?

Comment: Just wanted to say by the way, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are set on your way. you can consider duplicating data in order to join less times in a similar way to what is done in olap database.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube

With that said I don't think this is the best way to do it if you have 100 properties.

Comment: How would I implement this?

Comment: I'm also just saying 100 because it's the upper maximum I could conceive at the moment. It's highly unlikely it will reach that many, but I'd rather optimize for 100 vs 50 than have degrading performance past that point.

Comment: You might gain by splitting the main table, if you can categorize the lookups into "bands" based on frequency of use, or perhaps functional "modules". For example a religion value might only be entered once and change very very infrequently, but another lookup might change quite often. Sparseness is another factor to look at, whilst you might provision 50 or 100 lookups to the main table you might really only get 10 to 20 consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to export it to Microsoft Excel Power Pivot with Power Query? you can make fast data analysis with pretty awsome ways to show it with Power view  [video sample](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m94MowVO1w0)

Comment: Watched the video. And PowerPivot will optimize SQL queries?